# Show that $f_R(t)= \frac{1}{\pi^2R}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\pi Rs)}{s^2}(f(t+s)+f(t-s))ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ integrable. for all $R>0$ and $t\in  \mathbb{R}$. Define $ f_R(t) =\int_{-R}^{R}\left(1-\frac{|x|}{R}\right)\hat{f}(x) e^{2\pi itx} dx$.

Then show that $f_R(t)= \frac{1}{\pi^2R}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\pi Rs)}{s^2}(f(t+s)+f(t-s))ds$.

I'm a beginner in Fourier analysis so I need some hints to prove this statement.

Comment: @MarkViola  You're right  i accually missed $e^{2\pi itx}$ in first expression sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
f_R(t)&=\int_{-R}^R \left(1-\frac{|x|}{R}\right)e^{i2\pi tx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s)e^{-i2\pi sx}\,ds\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) \int_{-R}^R e^{i2\pi (t-s)x}\left(1-\frac{|x|}{R}\right)\,dx\,ds\tag2\\\\
&=\frac1{\pi^2R}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) \frac{\sin^2(\pi R(t-s))}{(t-s)^2}\,ds\tag3\\\\
&=\frac1{\pi^2R}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t+s)\frac{\sin^2(\pi Rs)}{s^2}\,ds\tag4\\\\
&=\frac1{\pi^2R}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(\pi Rs)}{s^2} (f(t-s)+f(t+s))\,ds\tag5
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**NOTES:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we applied Fubini-Tonelli to justify interchanging the order of integration.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we evaluated the inner integral and factored out the constant term $\frac1{\pi^2R}$.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we enforced the substitution $s\mapsto s+t$ and noted that the integrand is an even function.

And in going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we split the integral into integrals from $-\infty$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $\infty$.  Then, for the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$, we enforced the substitution $s\mapsto -s$.

Comment: +1 But may you please add some explanation?

Comment: @KamalSaleh Sure.  What specific question(s) do you have?

Comment: I actually have questions on all of them >D I don't get how the switching of the integral sign was done, how you factored the $\frac{1}{\pi^2R}$, and how $f(s-t)=f(t-s)+f(t+s)$

Comment: @MarkViola i think  you forget a minus there $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s)e^{-i2\pi sx}\,ds$ .

Comment: @KhalidKabouri Thank you.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I've added notes to explain each step.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks! Makes much more sense now.

Comment: @KamalSaleh You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @KhalidKabouri What was the motivation for this relationship?  You should consider adding that to your posted question.